# Sony SmartWatch 2 communication with Host Application on phone

Tags: sony-smartwatch

As i know host application for Sony products are responsable for communication between phone and accessory.

But, in bluetooth data transfer from phone to watch what is specially transferred?

For examle, My Extension data as a object array and layout which will be displayed passed to watch? Or all rendered 176x220px UI block is send from phone to watch.

In this transfer is there any security issues to be considered?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is passed to the watch from the host application, so it would be the complete 176x220 bitmap.

As far as security, Bluetooth data is encrypted in BT v2.1+ plus the user still has to pair the device and confirm a pairing code as with all BT devices.  So it's not any less secure than any other Bluetooth device on the market in that respect.